# Welche Buchstaben aus gebrochenen Schriften als Aufzählungszeichen in Listen?

Tags: typography, list, blackletter

Gibt es eine zuverlässige, allgemein anerkannte Quelle zu gebrochenen Schriften im Deutschen (also Fraktur & Co.), die genau beschreibt, welche Buchstaben in einer langen Liste als Aufzählungszeichen verwendet werden sollten?

Ich habe noch vor wenigen Jahren Mathematiker, Naturwissenschaftler und Ingenieure erlebt, die zumindest handschriftlich neben lateinischen und griechischen Buchstaben auch „deutsche“ (also Sütterlin o.ä.) für die Nummerierung tieferer Ebenen verwendet haben. Das waren etwa dieselben, die auch Vektoren damit bezeichnet haben.

Im Netz habe ich spontan wenig dazu gefunden. [Matthias Kammerer](http://www.matthias-kammerer.de/SonsTypo5.htm#aufzaehlung) meint, dass zumindest im laufenden Text vor schließender runder Klammer Antiqua-Buchstaben verwendet werden sollten bzw. wurden.

### Antizipierte Zweifelsfälle

- Großes *I* und *J* sehen in vielen gebrochenen Schriften identisch aus, daher sollten man wohl nicht beide verwenden und analog auch kleines *j* vermeiden.
- In noch älteren Schriften waren *U/u* und *V/v* nicht zu unterscheiden und *W/w* entsprach ihrer Verdoppelung, daher könnte ich mir gut vorstellen, dass in entsprechend langen Listen diese drei im Alphabet aufeinander folgenden Buchstaben zu einem einzigen Aufzählungszeichen zusammengefasst wurden.
- Sollte rundes *s* oder langes *ſ* verwendet werden?
- Was kommt nach *z*: *aa, ab, ac …* oder *aa, bb, cc …* oder etwas anderes?
  Werden ggf. *ch*, *ck*, *ss*, *st*, *tz* als Ligatur und *ii* als *ij* (wie manchmal bei römischen Zahlen) gesetzt?
- Welches Suffix und evtl. Präfix sollte verwendet werden?
  *(a), a), a., a:, a·, a-, a–, a—, a°, [a], a]* …

Comment: Ich stimme dafür diese Frage zu schließen, denn sie hat nichts mit der deutschen Sprache zu tun. Listen gibt es in allen Sprachen. Darüber hinaus sind z.B. in der Mathematik auch in fremdsprachigen Texten Fraktur-Buchstaben gleich häufig anzutreffen wie in deutschen Texten. Ich sehe daher nicht, wo hier die explizite Verbindung zur deutschen Sprache ist.

Comment: Wenn Du so viele Ebenen brauchst und so viele Punkte pro Ebene hast, dass Du auf Fraktur und Ligaturen ausweichen musst, hast Du ein strukturelles Problem.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: [Relevante Meta-Diskussion](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/81/2594)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Inwiefern soll diese Diskussion für diese Frage relevant sein? Bei der von dir verlinkten Meta-Diskusion geht es um Typografie. Bei der vorliegenden Frage ja wohl nicht. Typografie befasst sich mit der Gestaltung von Schrift, also mit dem Aussehen der verwendeten Schriftzeichen, mit der Größe von Abständen, usw. Typografie befasst sich aber **nicht** damit, welche Zeichen in einem Text zu verwenden sind. Hier wird aber ausdrücklich danach gefragt »*welche Buchstaben in einer langen Liste als Aufzählungszeichen verwendet werden sollten*«. Das ist nicht Typografie.

Comment: (Forts.) Regeln, die vorgeben, welche Zeichen man zur Kennzeichnung von Listenpunkten verwenden soll, gehören weder den Reich der Rechtschreibung noch der Grammatik und schon gar nicht der Typographie an. Das ist schlichtweg jedem frei überlassen. Normungen gibt es nur innerhalb von bestimmten Organisationen (Universitäten, EU, ...), diese sind aber in der Regel unabhängig von der verwendeten Sprache.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: *Typografie befasst sich mit der Gestaltung von Schrift* – Typografie ist der Einsatz von Schrift. Die Gestaltung von Schrift nennt man Schriftgestaltung. Und die Frage nach der Wahl der Schriftart, der eingrenzenden Klammern, und der Zeichen selbst ist sehr wohl Typografie, sofern sie nicht durch Rechtschreibung o. Ä. vorgegeben ist.

Comment: @Robert hat natürlich recht. Ich frage auch nicht wirklich für eine praktische Anwendung, sondern für [CSS Custom Counter Styles](http://www.w3.org/TR/predefined-counter-styles/), die prinzipiell bspw. auch für die Seitennummerierung verwendet werden können und daher einen möglichst großen Zahlenraum abdecken sollten. (Einige Stile gehen in die Millionen.)

Answer (score 4):

Zunächst ein paar Beispiele, die ich auf die Schnelle auftreiben konnte, alle aus Werken, die sich mit Sprache, Schrift u. Ä. befassen, also voraussichtlich mit erhöhter Sorgfalt gesetzt wurden:

1. Severing – Rede und Schrift (1923)

   [image]
2. Friesenhahn, Schwering – Handbuch der Reklame (Jahr unbekannt, nach 1900)

   [image]
3. Übelacker – Richtig Deutsch (1903)

   [image]
4. Duden (1926)

   [image]
5. Adelung – Grammatisch-kritisches Wörterbuch der Hochdeutschen Mundart (1793)

   [image]

   - Die Beispiele 1–4 bekräftigen zumindest für das zwanzigste Jahrhundert die Behauptung, dass man Antiqua-Buchstaben genutzt hat. Beispiel 5 zeigt aber auf, dass dies keine allgemeine Regel war.
   - Beispiel 3 nutzt mit dem Punkt einen anderen Abschluss als die anderen jüngeren Beispiele, die eine Klammer nutzen.
   - Den Adelung gibt oder gab es auch online. Wenn Du Glück hast, findest Du ein Wort mit hinreichend vielen Bedeutungen, dass zumindest Deine Frage nach der genutzten *s*-Variante beantwortet, wenn nicht gar, wie es nach *z* weiterging.
   - Nach meinem Einblick in die damalige Wahrnehmung des Alphabets würde ich erwarten dass *s* statt *ſ* genutzt wurde und das Ligaturen (sofern man denn so weit kam) nicht genutzt wurden. Es wurde ja zum Beispiel auch keine *ck*-Ligatur in Namen wie *Ranicki* genutzt.
   - Generell: Das Zeitalter der Fraktur in Deutschland war ein sehr langes und war nicht auch nur ansatzweise von einheitlichem Schriftsatz geprägt. Man bedenke, dass eine Standardisierung der Rechtschreibung erst Ende des 19. Jahrhunderts gelang. Allgemeingültige Grundsätze gab es eigentlich nie, auch wenn sich das viele heutige Frakturfreunde so wünschen. Viele der Aussagen auf der von Dir verlinkten Seite kann ich in dieser Allgemeinheit nicht bestätigen oder würde sie als falsch einstufen.

   Hinzu kommt, dass meiner Erfahrung nach viele zeitgenössische Regelwerke dazu neigten, die Welt so zu beschreiben, wie sie sie gerne gehabt hätten, aber nicht wie sie wirklich war. Sie sind also auch keine zuverlässige Quelle.

Comment: Danke, ich glaube, das beantwortet hinreichend die Frage nach Aufzählungen innerhalb von vorwiegend in gebrochenen Schriften gesetzten deutschen Texten, aber noch nicht die nach gezielt in Fraktur, Sütterlin o.ä. geschriebenen Aufzählungszeichen (im Antiquasatz) – ist mir auch gerade erst klar geworden, dass das zwei mglw. sehr verschiedene Aspekte sind.

Comment: PS: [Adelung](http://lexika.digitale-sammlungen.de/adelung/seite/bsb00009134_00037) verwendet `I. 1. (1) (a) α)` für die Gliederungsebenen der Einträge. Die Transkription der Bayerischen Staatsbibliothek verwendet `aa) bb) …` statt der griechischen Buchstaben. Mehr habe ich noch nicht herausgefunden.